# Simulation study for a Exponential Distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood, simulation, programming, descriptive-statistics

I have a pdf defined as:
$$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-b)}$$

Conduct a simulation study in R to explore the behaviour of the maximum likelihood estimator
$λ_{MLE}$ for λ on simulated data $X_1, · · · , X_n$ (as independent copies of X with parameter λ) according to the following instructions. Take b = 0.01 and consider a setting in which λ = 2 and generate a plot of the mean squared error as a function of the sample size n. You should consider a sample size between 100 and 5000 in increments of 10, and consider 100 trials per sample size. For each trial of each sample size generate a random sample $X_1, · · · , X_n$ (as independent copies of X with parameter λ = 2), then compute the maximum likelihood estimate $λ_{MLE}$ for λ based upon the corresponding sample. Display a plot of the mean square error of $λ_{MLE}$ as an estimator for λ as a function of the sample size n.

I don't really understand how to go about the simulation study. I don't need an answer, I just need an outline on how to approach the simulation. Probably should use a dexp() function in R right? What do they mean by a 100 trials in each sample size. Please help!

Comment: In R you simulate with the rexp function. They want you to repeat the process outlined for ever sample size 100 times, i.e. generate 100 samples from the sampling distribution of the MLE

Comment: Ah ok. But wouldn't using the same function a 100 times give me the same numbers again and again? Or are there differences each time?

Comment: Behind the scenes R uses a pseudo random number generator so you will get new random numbers unless you set a seed beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not want a complete answer and just an outline to follow, you can proceed as below:

1. Define a function `lambda_hat(sample)` which takes a sample and computes its MLE for the parameter $\lambda$.
2. Define another function to compute the Mean Square Error (MSE) of the estimator, as below:

```
MSE <- function(sample_size, lambda = 2, size = 100) {
    output <- 0
    # write a loop and in each iteration take a sample by rexp() function
    # compute its estimate for lambda and add the square error to `output`
    # at the end return `output` divided by `size`
    return(output/size)
}
```

Note that to compute the MSE of an estimator you need to compute the estimate a number of times and then take its average, which the instructions wants you to do that 100 times, and each time to compute the estimate you need a sample of a fixed size which comes from the vector `x` below.

3. Define a sequence `x <- seq(100, 5000, by = 10)`.
4. Compute the mean square error for each sample size in `x` by `y <- sapply(x, MSE)`.
5. Plot by `plot(x, y)`.